# Android sockets reconnect to server

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm building a android app that using connection with Java server (on computer).
I have a problem- when I find that there is no connection with the server, I'm trying to reconnect to the server but it doesn't work.
Here is the Client class code:

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask {

    private final int port = 1978;
    private final String ip = "192.168.14.22";
    private Socket socket;
    private DataOutputStream output;
    private DataInputStream input;


   public Client() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            Log.d("Network c1", "Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socket = null;
            Log.d("Network c1", "Not connected");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean checkConnection() {
        if (output == null)
            return false;
        try {
            output.writeUTF("abc");
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {

    }

}
```

And the Activity code:

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Client client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        client = new Client();
        client.execute();

        //I used timer because it didn't work without it- That saied always 'not connected' message/Toast
        new CountDownTimer(5, 0) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                check();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void check() {
        boolean isProcess;

        isProcess = !checkConnection();

        if (isProcess) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setMessage("Unable connect to the library");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //See note 1.
                    check();
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkConnection() {
        if (client.checkConnection()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to the library", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable connect to the library", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note 1:
The problem is here.

This Dialog need to be shown until the server/Library connected.

If the server **is on** before the app turned on, the `check()` method works well and says 'Connected successful' and the Dialog doesn't show.

But if when the app started, the server was unreachable, and turned on later (And became reachable)- the `check()` method don't work and always shows the Dialog.

What is the problem?

By the way, I tried to restart the client `AsyncTask Class`, but i didn't succeed.
(I tried to do `close(true)` to it, and after do `excute()` to it again, but the `cancel()` method didn't worked, and was a error that said that after a `AsyncTask Class` excuted, it can't excute again)

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you trying to reconnect?

Comment: I tried to do excute again, but it's not working. How can i reconnect in another way?

Answer (score 1):

You should not check for connectivity periodically (every couple of seconds like you do in this code).
Instead you should let the OS do this for you, it will be more reliable and more efficient in terms of battery and CPU.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726587/how-to-react-to-the-keep-alive-package-in-android)